# DeepDiff among Rows

Tags: python, pandas

i have this data frame

```
import pandas as pd
from deepdiff import DeepDiff
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_new': ['a','b','c,d','d'],
                   'col_old': ['a','e','d','d'],
                   'col_val': [True,False,False,True]})
print(df)
  col_new col_old  col_val
0       a       a     True
1       b       e    False
2     c,d       d    False
3       d       d     True
```

i want to replace every False value with the DeepDiff of that row
i tried this

```
df['col_val'] = df['col_val'].where(df['col_val'],DeepDiff(df['col_old'],df['col_new'])['values_changed'])
```

expected this

```
  col_new col_old                                            col_val
0       a       a                                               True
1       b       e  {'root': {'new_value': 'b', 'old_value': 'e'...
2     c,d       d  {'root': {'new_value': 'c,d', 'old_value': 'd...
3       d       d                                               True
```

but got this

```
  col_new col_old                                            col_val
0       a       a                                               True
1       b       e  {'root[1]': {'new_value': 'b', 'old_value': 'e...
2     c,d       d  {'root[1]': {'new_value': 'b', 'old_value': 'e...
3       d       d                                               True
```

**Edit: I'd like to thank jezrael for his perfect answer.**

But what if there are 10 or 20 columns, should I just type the same [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63596854/6790701) over and over?

Answer (score 2):

For me working apply function by [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for scalar processing, but only for `False` rows matched by inverted mask by `~`:

```
mask = df['col_val']
f = lambda x: DeepDiff(x['col_old'], x['col_new'])['values_changed']

df.loc[~mask, 'col_val'] = df[~mask].apply(f, axis=1)
print (df)
  col_new col_old                                           col_val
0       a       a                                              True
1       b       e    {'root': {'new_value': 'b', 'old_value': 'e'}}
2     c,d       d  {'root': {'new_value': 'c,d', 'old_value': 'd'}}
3       d       d                                              True
```

If thers is same pattern of columns names is possible use `f-string`s for matching:

```
from deepdiff import DeepDiff

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_new': ['a','b','c,d','d'],
                   'col_old': ['a','e','d','d'],
                   'col_val': [True,False,False,True],
                   'col1_new': ['a','b','c,d','d'],
                   'col1_old': ['a','e','d','d'],
                   'col1_val': [True,False,False,True],
                   'col2_new': ['a','b','c,d','d'],
                   'col2_old': ['a','e','d','d'],
                   'col2_val': [True,False,False,True]})
print(df)
```

---

```
cols = ['col','col1','col2']

for col in cols:
    mask = df[f'{col}_val']
    f = lambda x: DeepDiff(x[f'{col}_old'], x[f'{col}_new'])['values_changed']
    df.loc[~mask, f'{col}_val'] = df[~mask].apply(f, axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df)

  col_new col_old                                           col_val col1_new  \
0       a       a                                              True        a   
1       b       e    {'root': {'new_value': 'b', 'old_value': 'e'}}        b   
2     c,d       d  {'root': {'new_value': 'c,d', 'old_value': 'd'}}      c,d   
3       d       d                                              True        d   

  col1_old                                          col1_val col2_new  \
0        a                                              True        a   
1        e    {'root': {'new_value': 'b', 'old_value': 'e'}}        b   
2        d  {'root': {'new_value': 'c,d', 'old_value': 'd'}}      c,d   
3        d                                              True        d   

  col2_old                                          col2_val  
0        a                                              True  
1        e    {'root': {'new_value': 'b', 'old_value': 'e'}}  
2        d  {'root': {'new_value': 'c,d', 'old_value': 'd'}}  
3        d                                              True
```

If is necessary specify each triple of columns for processing use:

```
triples = [('col_new','col_old','col_val'),
           ('col1_new','col1_old','col1_val'),
           ('col2_new','col2_old','col2_val')]


for new, old, val in triples:
    mask = df[val]
    f = lambda x: DeepDiff(x[old], x[new])['values_changed']
    df.loc[~mask, val] = df[~mask].apply(f, axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df)
  col_new col_old                                           col_val col1_new  \
0       a       a                                              True        a   
1       b       e    {'root': {'new_value': 'b', 'old_value': 'e'}}        b   
2     c,d       d  {'root': {'new_value': 'c,d', 'old_value': 'd'}}      c,d   
3       d       d                                              True        d   

  col1_old                                          col1_val col2_new  \
0        a                                              True        a   
1        e    {'root': {'new_value': 'b', 'old_value': 'e'}}        b   
2        d  {'root': {'new_value': 'c,d', 'old_value': 'd'}}      c,d   
3        d                                              True        d   

  col2_old                                          col2_val  
0        a                                              True  
1        e    {'root': {'new_value': 'b', 'old_value': 'e'}}  
2        d  {'root': {'new_value': 'c,d', 'old_value': 'd'}}  
3        d                                              True
```

---

Another idea is reshape columns to only 3 columns by `pd.lreshape`, so is possible use original solution:

```
from deepdiff import DeepDiff

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_new': ['a','b','c,d','d'],
                   'col_old': ['a','e','d','d'],
                   'col_val': [True,False,False,True],
                   'col1_new': ['a','b','c,d','d'],
                   'col1_old': ['a','e','d','d'],
                   'col1_val': [True,False,False,True],
                   'col2_new': ['a','b','c,d','d'],
                   'col2_old': ['a','e','d','d'],
                   'col2_val': [True,False,False,True]})
print(df)
    col_new col_old  col_val col1_new col1_old  col1_val col2_new col2_old  \
0       a       a     True        a        a      True        a        a   
1       b       e    False        b        e     False        b        e   
2     c,d       d    False      c,d        d     False      c,d        d   
3       d       d     True        d        d      True        d        d   

   col2_val  
0      True  
1     False  
2     False  
3      True
```

---

```
new = [col for col in df.columns if col.endswith('new')]
old = [col for col in df.columns if col.endswith('old')]
val = [col for col in df.columns if col.endswith('val')]
df1 = pd.lreshape(df, {'new':new, 'old':old,'val':val})
print (df1)
    new old    val
0     a   a   True
1     b   e  False
2   c,d   d  False
3     d   d   True
4     a   a   True
5     b   e  False
6   c,d   d  False
7     d   d   True
8     a   a   True
9     b   e  False
10  c,d   d  False
11    d   d   True
```

---

```
mask = df1['val']
f = lambda x: DeepDiff(x['old'], x['new'])['values_changed']

df1.loc[~mask, 'val'] = df1[~mask].apply(f, axis=1)
print (df1)
    new old                                               val
0     a   a                                              True
1     b   e    {'root': {'new_value': 'b', 'old_value': 'e'}}
2   c,d   d  {'root': {'new_value': 'c,d', 'old_value': 'd'}}
3     d   d                                              True
4     a   a                                              True
5     b   e    {'root': {'new_value': 'b', 'old_value': 'e'}}
6   c,d   d  {'root': {'new_value': 'c,d', 'old_value': 'd'}}
7     d   d                                              True
8     a   a                                              True
9     b   e    {'root': {'new_value': 'b', 'old_value': 'e'}}
10  c,d   d  {'root': {'new_value': 'c,d', 'old_value': 'd'}}
11    d   d                                              True
```

Comment: excuse me but what if I wanted to run that code but for lots of columns, should I keep replicating the same code over and over?